# Advise on Magento setup for Multi Store switcher by postcode

Tags: magento, geolocation, multistore

Hi I wonder if anyone could offer some advice.

I'm developing a one site, multi store magento install for a food delivery service. I need customer to enter postcode, find their nearest physical store which will then auto switch to corresponding Magento store. (each store has different product catalogue).

Geo Ip looks like the right sort of route but it seems only based on country and I need to be more specific than that.

Answer (score 0):

You can get more specificity than just country with GeoIP, especially with paid service, but the accuracy goes down the more specific you get. As far as switching stores automatically, you can implement that by loading the appropriate store for the customer and then redirect them:

```
$storeCode = 'store_code_to_send_customer_to';

$store = Mage::app()->getSafeStore($storeCode);
if ($store->getCode() == NULL) {
    $store = Mage::app()->getDefaultStoreView();
}

$storeUrl = $store->getCurrentUrl(false);
Mage::app()->getResponse()->setRedirect($storeUrl)->sendResponse();
die();
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for answer, can you explain further? I can't quite understand how this works from frontend

Comment: @user3647897 - This is meant to be incorporated into an observer that you create in an extension.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by creating a module, Module consists following fields :

- Store Name
- Postal Code
- Longitude and Latitude (if more tan one store exists per postal code)

and other information regarding store, but this is compulsorily.

Now how it works, when ever user search for a Postcode filter the data according to that store and redirects the customer to that store.

Comment: Both of these comments seem really helpful so thanks. I've found some free extensions of store locators that would handle the fields of store name. postal code, longitude and laitutde. So once I've set up an input box that customer should enter postcode. If postcode matches any from the field in extension, then products from that store should be shown. Does that sound feasible?

Comment: @user3647897 Can you please share the extension that you used, I'm also looking for the similar kind of solution

Comment: @doubtman I build my own custom extension which fulfills my requirement

Comment: @ Deepak Mankotia,  Can you please help me here, I have created 2 stores in Magento which are in two different states. By entering the zip code the store has to be loaded accordingly...